# How to drag folders to the extreme left on desktop in unity 7.4.0

Tags: unity

I would like to know how to drag and drop my folders to the left most part of the desktop in Ubuntu 16.04.

Notice the gap between the taskbar and the folders in the image.

[image: desktop_ss]

Comment: Try to change the launcher to auto hide then moving the icons to the left then change it back to always visible.

Comment: The icons do shift a bit to the left when the launcher is set to auto-hide but they come back to their original position when the launcher is again set to always visible.

Comment: Just a hunch, but could you check what the output of `wmctrl -lG | grep Desktop` is? You might have to install `wmctrl` first: `sudo apt-get install wmctrl`.

Comment: @JacobVlijm , this is what I get after running wmctrl -lG | grep Desktop
0x01c0000a -1 0    0    1366 768  host_name Desktop

Comment: Ah, sorry, my hunch was wrong. Theoretically, the desktop is a window, which can get moved by whatever process (I've been there), causing the icons to be out of place. Obviously, you desktop starts at 0, 0.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Ok, then according to the theory, is it possible to move the icons to the left or this is as good as it gets?

Comment: Icons can be placed via cli, but there is a marge on the left. The distance in your image seems big though, but I am not sure if this is "normal" for Unity, I don't use Unity anymore.